# What are the good java based pop3 email listeners?

Tags: java, listener, jakarta-mail

We need to build a functionality to listen to new incoming emails using the pop3.

Is there any tool or api which provides this functionality?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html)...